# Error 0x8007007e When trying to mount WinPE 5 wim in Windows 7 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, dism

Using ADK for Windows 8.1, and the DISM cmdlets that come with them. I have WMF 4.0 installed. My machine is Windows 7 x64 SP1, and I'm trying to mount the wim using

```
PS C:\Users\BigHomie> Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\
en-us\winpe.wim' -Path C:\WinPE_x86 -index 1
```

And receive the following error:

```
Mount-WindowsImage : DismInitialize failed. Error code = 0x8007007e
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\8.1\Assessmen ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Mount-WindowsImage], COMExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.MountWindowsImageCommand
```

Using dism.exe works fine.

**Update**

Forgetting I had this problem, I went to mount a wim using the Powershell ISE and actuallygot a visual error message about

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l4-1-0.dll"
```

not being installed. After checking that the dll did in fact exist in the folder I called regsvr32 and received *another* error message

[image]

Will try reinstalling as recommended.

Comment: the code means ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND. Run ProcMon in background to see which DLLs can't be loaded: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the path to the dism module to the environment variable path example: $env:Path = ($env:Path + ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM")